# AJAX call on pageload for listitems

Tags: ajax, list, jquery-mobile, pageload

Currently I have a list of items (`<ul><li>item</li>...</ul>`) in a JQuery Mobile environment.
Now I want to show additional information for each item in the list, since the required information can take some time before its fetched, I'm looking for a way where when the page is loaded, each item sends an AJAX request and while doing so a spinner is shown as a placeholder. When the result of the AJAX call is shown, an icon should take the place of the spinner

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list, you can add `data-attributes` to the list-items to store an ID or whatever you use to identify the data you will grab for the specific list-item:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="my-listview">
    <li data-id="3348"><img src="/css/images/loading.gif" /></li>
</ul>
```

Note that if you use the GIF version of the jQuery Mobile loading spinner, it will animate on its own.

Then you can use the callback function of each AJAX request to add the data to each list-item:

```
//cache all list-items
var $listItems = $('#my-listview').children();

//loop through each list-item
$.each($listItems, function (index, element) {

    //cache this specific list-item for later use (in the callback)
    var $listItem = $listItems.eq(index);
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'some-script.php',
        data    : { id : $(this).attr('data-id') },
        type    : 'post',
        success : function (response) {

            //if the server returns valid HTML, we can just append it to the list-item
            $listItem.find('img').replaceWith(response);
        },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            /*Don't forget to handle errors*/
            $listItem.find('img').replaceWith('<span>An error occured, please try again later.</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: overall this seems to be working quite well, however the replacing of the img by the response doesn't do anything, any tips?

Comment: I updated my answer to fix this. Basically the AJAX callback was appending the HTML in the wrong spot. To fix this I changed the code to replace the spinner image with the HTML from the server-response. This way you will place the AJAX returned HTML in the proper place.